# How to fill a Mock<DbSet> in Nunit with Moq?

Tags: testing, entity-framework-core, nunit, moq

I am trying to fill a mock dbset with a testentity but I only get exception after exception. I am very new to Nunit testing and haven't really got the hang of it. I am trying to test a simple delete method in my repository, here is the code for the method:

```
public async Task DeleteQuestion(Question questionToRemove)
    {
        if (questionToRemove is not null)
        {
            var questionsAnswers = await _context.Answers.Where(a => a.Question == questionToRemove).ToListAsync();
            foreach (Answer a in questionsAnswers)
            {
                _context.Answers.Remove(a);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            _context.Questions.Remove(questionToRemove);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                
            var questions = await _context.Questions.Where(q => q.Quiz == questionToRemove.Quiz).ToListAsync();
            int order = 1;
            foreach (Question question in questions)
            {
                question.QuestionOrderId = order;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                order++;
            }
        }

    }
```

And here is the test that I have written:

```
 public async Task DeleteQuestionFunction()
    {
        //Arrange
        Question testQuestion = new Question { QuestionId = 1, QuestionText = "Test" };
        Answer testAnswer = new Answer { Question = testQuestion, AnswerId = 1, AnswerText = "TestAnswer" };
        _appDBContextMock.SetupAdd(x => x.Questions.Add(testQuestion));
        _appDBContextMock.SetupAdd(x => x.Answers.Add(testAnswer));

        //Act
        var questionListcomponent = new QuestionListComponent();
        questionListcomponent.DeleteQuestion(testQuestion);

        var testresult = await _questionRepositoryMock.Object.GetQuestionById(testQuestion.QuestionId);

        //Assert
        Assert.That(testresult, Is.Null);

    }
```

When I only used the Setup method I got this exception:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x =>
> x.Questions Non-overridable members (here: AppDbContext.get_Questions)
> may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

and right now with the SetupAdd function I get this exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of class:
> TietoQuiz.Models.DbContexts.AppDbContext. Could not find a
> parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments')

I think my problem is that I don't know how to set up a mock dbset properly. I tried to Google, but I found so many different ways and so many comments saying "that is not recommended/ the wrong way"! It is very confusing for a newbie, so I hope someone here can help!

Comment: You have found right answers. Use InMemory Provider or InMemory Sqlite provider. Mocking DbSet is wasting of time.

Comment: The code is wrong to begin with. A DbContext is a multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-Work and `SaveChanges` is meant to be called *only once at the end* to persist all pending changes in a single internal database transaction. The way the method is written, should anything happen you'll end up with mismatched questions and answers. It also takes 2*N times longer than using EF properly

Comment: `I found so many different ways and so many comments saying "that is not recommended/ the wrong way"!` because it is. It's very bad. Mocking DbSet is pointless anyway, unless you're in the github/efcore repo, writing a unit test for EF Core itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a test by using a context, you must create your own context and verify the data after running it. You cannot use mocks with non overridable methods.

You must use a temporary file to create this context not to change your production database.